# 3d Object Position Leap Motion

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi i am New in Unity i am Working on a Project VR BASED HUMAN BODY STUDY Using Leap Motion i am Facing a problem when ever i Import 3 d Objects on My scene it is not in Perfect Position so that i can easily rotate the 3d object using Leap Motion and easily Click on UI buttons?

I purchase Custom Pointer from Unity Asset Store which Help me to Click On UI buttons Using Leap Motion but when ever I import my 3d Model it is not in Such Position that i can easily interact with both UI Buttons and 3d Objects at the same time ?

I just wants to Rotate and Grab my 3d Object Using Leap Motion and Click on UI buttons ..

[image]

Comment: Please add pictures, I don't understand a bit

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUjcl.png  is the Link and i added a Image Link above Kindly check it. I just wants to Click on UI buttons and at the Same time Interacting with my Heart ??

Answer (score 0):

Here I found Solution ..I just open my Scene which Having Custom Pointer Buttons and just Import 3d Model and set its position near my Leap Hand Models without Changing the Position of Menu and Buttons ..and Yes its solve my Problem